# Autosave specific workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

```
Sub Autosave()
    Dim FileName As String
    FileName = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Text

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="C:\Users\PC\Desktop\" & FileName _
    , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

How to save a specific workbook which are opened

Comment: If you are talking about saving the workbook that is open just use `ActiveWorkbook.Save`

Comment: I have a code for saving the opened excel file , but the challenge is that the I have more than 2 workbooks opened.

Sub Macro1()

 Sheets("Sheet1").Select
 Sheets("Sheet1").Copy
End Sub

Sub Autosave()
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\PCname\Desktop\" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Text, _
FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub

1st code create new book from the raw file on which all calculations are done. New File name is "Book1"

2nd code saves the active workbook, but doesnt save the new created book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the open workbooks like this

```
For Each w In Application.Workbooks 

    'You can simply save the current book
    w.Save 

    'Or get the name and save it to a location as you were

    Dim FileName As String
    FileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="C:\Users\PC\Desktop\" & FileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

Next w
```